# Definition on ordinal as a transitive well-ordered set

Tags: elementary-set-theory

The transitivity of set $\alpha$ is normally defined as "if $\beta \in \alpha$ then $\beta \subseteq \alpha$. One definition of ordinals states that $\alpha$ is an ordinal if it's a well-ordered set which is also transitive. I see how "$\beta \in \alpha$ implies $\beta \subset \alpha$" would work, but I have a problem with $\subseteq$, that is, I can't see how we can have both "$\alpha$ is well-ordered" and $\beta \in \alpha$ implies $\beta = \alpha$. We assume ZFC including the Axiom of Foundation. Thanks.

Comment: If $\beta\in \alpha$, then $\beta\ne \alpha$. But saying $\beta\in\alpha $ implies $\beta\subseteq\alpha$, isn’t wrong, it’s just slightly weaker  than the also-correct statement that $\alpha\in\beta$ implies $\alpha\subsetneq \beta$.

Comment: Perhaps a better way to think about "transitive" is : $\alpha$ is transitive if and only if $\gamma\in\beta$ and $\beta\in\alpha$ implies $\gamma\in\alpha$.

Comment: Yes, "$a<b$ implies $a\le b$ example makes a good point. I guess the problem I have is that some books use $a\subset b$ regardless of whether $a$ is a proper subset of $b$ or $a = b$, whereas some other books are very rigorous and write $a\subseteq b$ when they want to imply that "it is possible that $a=b$ and $a\subset b$ otherwise". In one course we used $a\subset b$ meaning either $a$ is a proper subset of $b$ or $a=b$ and $a\subsetneq b$ to emphasize the fact that $a$ is strictly a proper subset of $b$. So, when I saw $a\subseteq b$ my instant reaction was like "it is possible that $a=b$".